# Pick up a particular file from a directory using regex in Talend

Tags: regex, talend

My directory contains files named as WM_PersonFile_22022018 , WM_PersonFile_23022018, WM_PersonFile_24022018 , WM_PersonFile_25022018 and these files come on a daily basis. I am using tFileList to iterate through the files

What should be my regex in my Filemask to pick up the most recent file? Should the Use Global Expressions as Filemask be unchecked?

I tried  "*.txt" which is picking up all the files.

Answer (score 1):

RegEx would help you to filter for the correct files.

Some other logic would get you the newest file. If you use tFileList, you might be able to sort after date and only take the first result.

Alternatively, if you also want to check the date in the filename is correct, you might need to add a little logic with a tMap, tAssert, tJava or tJavaRow.